# foreach loop working only for first record of database in php

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

I am stuck in one condition in my code. I am sending gcm push notifications to multiple user from php. I am getting the reg id's from the database. In code I am using foreach loop to send notification. But I am not sure why it is sending the push notification to only one user not to the all user. if I remove the push notification code then it will show me all the reg ids from the database.

```
<?php
$host_name = "localhost";
$user_name = "xxxxxxx";
$user_pass = "xxxxx";
$db_name = "xxxxxx";

$conn=mysql_connect($host_name,$user_name,$user_pass);

if(!$conn) {
    echo"could not connect:".mysql_error();
} else {
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn);
}

$query = "select reg_id from property_register where reg_id != ''";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

foreach(mysql_fetch_array($result) as $r_id) {
    $gcmRegID  =  $r_id[0];
    echo $gcmRegID . "<br>";

    $pushMessage = "New Property Posted in CPO";
    if (isset($gcmRegID) && isset($pushMessage)) {
        $gcmRegIds = array($gcmRegID);
        $message = array("m" => $pushMessage); 

        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $gcmRegIds,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        // Update your Google Cloud Messaging API Key
        define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);       

        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

In short foreach loop is sending the notification to the first user only not to all. If  I remove the gcm code and do echo of foreach loop records its show me all

Thanks

Comment: You are returning.

Comment: yeah i know its required. otherwise push notification will not work.. Any suggestion for this? @KiwiJuicer

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why this should be required when the curl request is successfull. It will simply return you result to whereever you have called the function from.

Comment: If you return, it stops the current script, and that's why you only get the first one. How are you using that variable `$result` later anyway?

Comment: No use of $result later @Qirel

Comment: Then why return it at all...?

Comment: if did not return it will not sent push notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a return in your foreach loop, this will cause the first pass through the foreach to fire the retrun call and never loop through another foreach. The return is not needed. Use the following code instead.

```
<?php
$host_name = "localhost";
$user_name = "xxxxxxx";
$user_pass = "xxxxx";
$db_name = "xxxxxx";

$conn=mysql_connect($host_name,$user_name,$user_pass);

if(!$conn) {
    echo"could not connect:".mysql_error();
} else {
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn);
}

$query = "select reg_id from property_register where reg_id != ''";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

foreach(mysql_fetch_array($result) as $r_id) {
    $gcmRegID  =  $r_id[0];
    echo $gcmRegID . "<br>";

    $pushMessage = "New Property Posted in CPO";
    if (isset($gcmRegID) && isset($pushMessage)) {
        $gcmRegIds = array($gcmRegID);
        $message = array("m" => $pushMessage); 

        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $gcmRegIds,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        // Update your Google Cloud Messaging API Key
        define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);       

        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
?>
```